# Datatables: how to checkbox checked status change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

My table powered by datatable is 100% working now.

I am now trying to improved look&feel using a custom render function to use more beautiful checkbox.

Actually when I click on a row's checkbox, the row is selected, the counter of selected rows is updated and so on.

But I must 'react' to status change to update the visual side of my custom checkbox.

I tried to add a console.log() to render function and I discovered that it's executed only when doing the first draw with data returned from server, because I'm using ajax.

Is there a function, similar to render, called instead when checkbox value changes?

More precise indications:

- Commonly, we have a TD with a INPUT[type=checkbox] as direct child
- Now I have TD > DIV > INPUT[type=checkbox]
- Commonly, when user check a checbox, the input receive the checked attribute, and browser draw it in the appropriate way based on checked or not status
- Now I have no 'checked' attribute automatically set.

So I need to 'intercept' when datatable select the row and apply/remove the 'checked' attribute.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you post some of your code.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assign function to checkbox when onchange the save the values

```
$("#table").on('draw.dt', function() {
// call the function of your saved values do the code
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!  that solved a +4hour searching journey 